# Как сказать боту что бы он отправил сообщение в другой канал discord.py

Tags: python, discord

учусь писать дискорд ботов на питоне. Не могу разобраться как сказать боту, что бы он отсылал сообщение (что-то типа: человек захотел вывести n-нную сумму) в канал #какой-то, при написании человеком команды !withdraw в другом канале

```
@client.command(aliases = ['withdraw'])
async def __withdraw(ctx, amount: int = None):
    balance = cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]
    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author.mention}**, укажите сумму, которую желаете вывести")
    elif balance < amount:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{ctx.author.mention}** На вашем счету нету минимальной суммы вывода!"))
    else:
        if balance < 10000:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{ctx.author.mention}** Минимальная сумма вывода - 10.000 :dollar:"))

        else:
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{ctx.author.mention}** Заявка принята. Ожидайте! :slight_smile:", color = 0x52f04f))
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {}".format(amount, ctx.author.id))
            connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужен конкретный канал, то получаем его id и объявляем через бота:

`my_channel = client.get_channel(id)`

Для отправки сообщения строка `await my_channel.send('Текст сообщения')`

**Примерно такой код:**

```
my_channel = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     global my_channel
     my_channel = client.get_channel(id)

@client.command()
async def your_command(ctx):
     global my_channel
     await my_channel.send('Текст сообщения')
```

---

Но правильнее будет получить список всех каналов сервера и также выбрать нужный из них.

```
for channel in client.get_guild(ID сервера).channels:
    print(channel.id)
```

Comment: Не подскажете как узнать айди канала?

Comment: @Andrey341, нужно в настройках дискорда, на вкладке "Внешний вид", включить пункт "Режим разработчика". После этого, кликнув правой кнопкой мыши на любой объект, в самом низу у вас будет кнопка "Копировать ID. Так можно получать id пользователей, каналов и т.п.

Comment: Что-то оно ошибку мне выдает. _AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'_ @denisnumb

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы определяете объект канала после того, как пытаетесь отправить в него сообщение. Либо объявляете `channel` за пределами функций бота, когда он еще не подключен. Если у вас есть функция `on_ready()`, закиньте строку `my_channel = client.get_channel(id)` в нее. Тогда бот при включении сразу же получит объект канала

Comment: @Andrey341, вообщем, дополнил ответ кодом. Примерно такая структура должна быть

Comment: Человеческое спасибо  Долго искал решение @denisnumb